# Ignoring bad SSL certs on HttpWebRequest calls

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate

I have a multi-threaded application that calls a number of URL's from Parallel.ForEach loop.  For some of those URL's I need to ignore bad certificates for some I should not.

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback seems to provide global handling of all certificate validation callbacks.

Can anyone give a suggestion on how I can selectively accept bad certificates in a mutli-threaded Parallel.ForEach() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the best way to do this is to make a HashSet of URL's to ignore. If the url isn't something in your set of url's to ignore, then you can deal with bad certificates.

```
private Hashset<string> UrlWhiteList
...
private bool shouldIgnore(string url){
return UrlWhiteList.Contains(url);
}
```